# Java Encryption NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, bouncycastle

this is my code:

```
static {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
}
```

...

> final Cipher sifra = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");

Junit works fine but When I deploy my application to weblogic server I got these exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding
```

Can you hlp me what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the old strange problem of different versions and missing cryptography files. I believe PKCS5Padding instead of PKCS7Padding will work. Anyway, it has something to do with Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files which can be downloaded [from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) ... or some other missing part or old version of Java Cryptography Extension.

Comment: hm that is nice but I have to use PKCS7 not 5

Comment: They are effectively interchangeable for block sizes up to 256. Absolutely the same. But if you must, then the Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files are your ticket to ride.

Comment: it is a business requirement so I have no choice

Comment: ok I add security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider to java.security file and now it works thx a lot vdaka :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I am facing the same issue. the app works all good locally but the error comes out when it runs on a remote Jboss application server